# How many submissions can be made using praw at a time?

Tags: reddit, praw

I used praw to submit a link on a subreddit, but when I tried to add one more it asked me to do it after an hour. But when I do the same thing using the reddit site, It allows me to add as many links as I want. Does praw inhibits us to add more than one link per hour per user or is it checked by reddit api?

Answer (score 0):

The [answer is still no](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1zrysj/praw_how_many_submissions_can_be_made_using_praw/). Asking the question a fifth time will not change that.

Comment: Is something wrong in asking the same question to a different community of people? If I am stuck at a problem and I want to do my best to find a solution for it, I don't think it is not worth trying asking it again. Sorry if you got irritated reading the same question on two different sites but I wanted to make sure that I try my best.